# Using base class protected methods inside overriden (new) function of derived class

Tags: .net, inheritance, protected, managed-c++, overriding

I was trying to acomplish something similar to Java **"super"** call which i thought would be possible in this way :

```
public ref class base {

public: base(){}

protected: virtual void funct()
{
   MessageBox::Show("base funct");
}
};

public ref class derived : public base
{
public: derived() : base(){}

protected: virtual void funct() new
{
((Base^)this)->funct();
///some work
}
};
```

But it gives me *"Candidate function(s) not accesible"* error. Doesn't **"protected"** modifier gives acces to base class elements to all its subclasses?
I dont know if it makes any difference but Base class method that i want to override is inherited by Base aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, you can call base functions like this.

```
base::funct();
```

It complains because, after the cast, you have an instance of `base`. The `funct()` function is protected, therefore you can't call it on a given instance of `base`.

Comment: It worked thx. First time i used literaly "base" cuz i thought it might be an expression like in c# :P